Getting *"RootCoordClient mess key not exist"* when running a custom build of Milvus standalone without docker with embedded etcd
When running Milvus server from the deb file installation - it works OK, But when trying to run it from a custom build of standalone (without docker, with embedded etcd, with the same milvus.yaml file of the installation) - I am getting "RootCoordClient mess key not exist". It seems that the RootCoord client is unable to find a necessary key in its configuration. Specifically, it's indicating that a key named "rootcoord" does not exist, which the client is attempting to use. Anyone is familiar with this issue?
